# Multiple Query Search with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to query to find specific users based on certain credentials.

The query will only look in the User class.

First, I want the query to match the currentUser's location

Second, must match a specific category (meaning multiple users in the same location may be under the same category)

Here's what I have tried:

```
self.profileObj = [self.currentUser objectForKey:@"city"];

PFQuery * queryOne = [PFUser query]; 
[queryOne whereKey:@"city" equalTo:self.profileObj];

PFQuery * queryTwo = [PFUser query]; 
[queryTwo whereKey:@"category" equalTo:self.tagString];

PFQuery * query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryOne, queryTwo]]; 
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(NSArrayobjects, NSError error)
```

This is returning 0 results.

Comment: How does your Parse database looks like? At a glance the code looks alright, there might just be no data matching your query in Parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two separate queries since you are querying on the same User object. Also, I believe you want two AND constraints rather than OR? If so, you can just chain together two whereKeys:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"]; 
[query whereKey:@"city" equalTo:self.profileObj];
[query whereKey:@"category" equalTo:self.tagString];
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     ...
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this earlier, but must of had a typo I overlooked so it did not work. This looks to be working now.